# About probability matrix

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and let P be an $m\times m$ probability matrix, that is, each column of P consists of nonnegative real numbers adding up 1. Show that $||P^{n}||$ remains bounded as $n \to \infty$ , where $||.||$ is the operator norm of $P^{n}$ regarded as a linear operator $\mathbb{R^{m}}\to \mathbb{R^{m}}$ where $\mathbb{R^{m}}$ is taken with its standard norm).

My attempt:
It is easy to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, every entry of $P^{n}$ is in $[0,1]$. Since all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional space, I take the maximum norm $||.||_{\infty}$ for $P^{n}$.So  $||P^{n}||_{\infty} \leq 1$ for any $n \in\mathbb{N}$. So $||P^{n}||$ remains bounded as $n \to \infty$  where $||.||$ is the operator norm of $P^{n}$

Can anyone check my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but, as some refinement, let me note that $P^n$ is a probability matrix for every $n$ (which in particular implies that the entries of $P^n$ lie in $[0,1]$).  This is easy to prove by induction on $n$:
$$
 \sum_k P^n_{jk}=\sum_{k,s}P^{n-1}_{js}P_{sk}=\sum_s \left(P^{n-1}_{js}\sum_k P_{sk}\right)=
\sum_s P^{n-1}_{js}=1
$$
by the induction assumption.